# Difference between an Array of null versus a null Array

Tags: java, arraylist

Given the code below:

```
List<Object> arrayList = new ArrayList<Object>();
for(int counter=0; counter < 100; counter++) {
  arrayList.add(null);
}
```

Aside from the instantiated and having the size 100, how different "arrayList" from a List which is actually null?

Just curious.

Thanks.

Comment: In most cases you are simply moving place where `NullPointerException` will be thrown deeper. But it actually depend on how you will use `arrayList`.

Comment: There is nothing "bad" with `null` values *until* you try to do `null.something`.

Comment: @Pshemo: the problem I have is not actually the usage of the array list but the entries inside it being stale. once I pass through the specific index of an array, I have to either, remove that index of the array or refer it to null. This way, the list is cleaned. But I took the route of cleaning the list every after some specific number of indexes. :)
Thanks though. ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first: an `ArrayList<...>` is not an array, the `ArrayList` is quite more sophisticated, but uses an array as backing datastructure.

Now to your question: The two main differences which come to my mind are those:

- a reference pointing to `null` consumes much less memory than an actual `ArrayList` of size 100. Note that the references are of same size, but the reference pointing to `null` does not point to allocated memory. For the `ArrayList` with 100 `null` entries, all references to the 100 emelemts do exist, but refernce to `null`, making it consume more memory.
- you cannot call methods on `null`:

  ```
  List<Object> list1 = new ArrayList<Object>(100);
  list1.size(); // totally fine, will return 0
  List<Object> list2 = null;
  list2.size(); // throws a NullPointerException
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Very simple. If you have an `ArrayList` which is null, it is just a null object reference like any other (with a specific type assigned to it).

If you have an `ArrayList` of 100 null elements, then it is a fully instantiated `ArrayList` encapsulating 100 null object references.

*Functionally*, you can refer to any of those 100 null references without generating an exception. Whereas with a null `ArrayList`, any attempt to access a specific member of the list will generate an exception.

In practice, just as a backgrounder, it is generally a good idea to return an instantiated collection from any method that returns a collection. It enables calling code to generically enumerate the collection even if it contains zero instances of whatever it is supposed to contain.  Of course, opinions may vary. ;-)

Comment: Thanks. It's nice knowing that I wasn't wrong with my thinking. :)

Answer (score 0):

A list will be null if its variable has been defined but has not been declared as a new ArrayList.

```
List<String> nullList;
List<String> emptyList = new ArrayList<String>();
//empty list has been defined as a new ArrayList so it is not null, however it is empty because it has no elements
emptyList.add(null);
//empty list is still empty since all values are null
```

So when doing this:

```
nullList == null
```

would return true, but:

```
emptyList == null
```

would return false